# Cannot connect signal from an outer shared library to overloaded slot of QWidget derived class

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, function-pointers, signals-slots

I try to connect the signal from an outer shared library to an overloaded slot of base QWidget class's slot.

Suppose `this` is an instance of a class derived from `QWidget`

```
class MyClass : public QWidget;
...

MyClass* this_instance = new MyClass;
```

I tried the following approach

```
connect(obj_from_sl, SIGNAL(signalFromSL()), this, SLOT(update()); 
// update() is QWidget's slot
// the "sl" suffixs stands for "shared library"
```

but it didn't work. I have got linker errors. I have searched and found out, that
it is impossible to connect signal from an outer shared library using `SIGNAL`/ `SLOT` macros inside the `connect` function. It might be possible if I use function pointers.

OK. Let's change the signature:

```
connect(obj_from_sl, &ClassFromSL::signalFromSL, this, &QWidget::update);
                                                       ^ error comes here
```

and voilà

> cannot determine which instance of an overloaded function "`QWidget::update`" is intended.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QWidget::update()` function has different arguments, so it requires explicit casting for the new signal/slot syntax use

```
connect(obj_from_sl, &ClassFromSL::signalFromSL, this, static_cast<void (QWidget::*) )>(&QWidget::update));
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem regarding the syntax error. But I couldn't reach my target. The slot is still not working.

Comment: I also have tried to cast it but failed. Happy that this time it worked

Comment: @arsdever, you asked about the overloading issue so please accept my answer, regarding the update slot, did you test if the signal is actually emitting?

Comment: If you are using C++14 or newer, you can also use the qOverload function: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload